# meaning of 'do someone cold'

Tags: meaning

"One move, lights out. I’ll do you cold."

It's a dialogue between a criminal and a victim. (from TV series)

I do understand 'one move, lights out'
It means 'if you move, I will kill you', right?
But what does 'I'll do you cold.' mean?

I can't find it on dictionary or Google.
Help me!

(I'm not an American. Please talk to me nicely. :-(()

Comment: You will become cold.  (As in "dead".)

Comment: @HotLicks And cold has a registry sense of dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret this in line with [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock) definition of knock, which refers to "knock cold" as definition 2a(1) [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock%20out), under the verb to *knock out*.

Entry 4b [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold)...refers to "giving the appearance of being dead: unconscious"

And "do" has a sense of "to treat or make," usually heard in the phrase "do me wrong," meaning to treat me badly. Look at sense 11 [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do).

Answer (score 0):

No need to dig deep in the dictionaries, as the meaning is plain and obvious.

Cold - means dead, practically.
Do you - implies that he will have sexual intercourse with the body.

To prove it;

- This show is all about rapists.
- A moment prior he kissed her in the mouth.

external links:
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=do+you [second definition]
Had a man done so, he would have got called [necrophiliac](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/necrophiliac).

P.S. The Original Poster asked `Please talk to me nicely`,
yet the first response was `You will become cold. (As in "dead".)`